# Conditionally overwrite destination if no destination object is used

Tags: automapper

I would like to setup an Automapper mapping that follows the following rules.

- If the "in place" destination syntax is not used, map a particular member to a value
- If an object is passed in, then use the destination value

I've tried this every way I can think of.  Something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.RowCreatedDateTime, opt => {
        opt.Condition(dest => dest.DestinationValue == null);
        opt.UseValue(DateTime.Now);
     });
```

This always maps the value.  Essentially what I want is this:

```
c = Mapper.Map<A, B>(a, b);  // does not overwrite the existing b.RowCreatedDateTime
c = Mapper.Map<B>(a);        // uses DateTime.Now for c.RowCreatedDateTime
```

Note:  A does not contain a RowCreatedDateTime.

What are my options here?  It's very frustrating since there appears to be no documentation on the Condition method, and all the google results seem to be focused around where the source value is null, rather than the destination.

EDIT:

Thanks to Patrick, he got me on the right track..

I figured out a solution.  If anyone has a better way of doing this, please let me know.  Note I had to reference `dest.Parent.DestinationValue` rather than `dest.DestinationValue`.  For some reason, `dest.DestinationValue` is always null.

```
.ForMember(d => d.RowCreatedDateTime, o => o.Condition(d => dest.Parent.DestinationValue != null))
.ForMember(d => d.RowCreatedDateTime, o => o.UseValue(DateTime.Now))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to set up two mappings: one with the `Condition` (which determines IF a mapping should be performed) and one which defines what to do if the `Condition` returns true.  Something like this:

```
.ForMember(d => d.RowCreatedDateTime, o => o.Condition(d => d.DestinationValue == null);
.ForMember(d => d.RowCreatedDateTime, o => o.UseValue(DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  It overwrites the passed in value every time.

Comment: It turns out, you have to reference the parent.DestinationValue, but i've upvoted anyways.

Comment: This is wrong.  The d.DestinationValue is not a destination value.  It is a source value.  Condition takes a Func<Source, bool>.  You seem to tbe under the impression it takes Func<Dest, bool>.  This will not map if the source value is null, and does not pay attention to the state of the destination value